# Can I export/require a module in Node.js to be used without a var holding its objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, custom-error-handling

I am creating my own error library to have a custom catalog of specific and well documented errors to return on my API. I am doing something like this:

```
module.exports = CError;

function CError () {
}

// CUSTOM ERROR TYPES
CError.EmptyParamError = createErrorType(...);
CError.InvalidFormatError = createErrorType(...);
```

A sample of how I use my custom error types right now:

```
CError = require('cerror');

if(!passwd)
    callback(new CError.EmptyParamError(passwd, ...));
```

I will use this errors through my entire project and I wish to have a cleaner code like this: (without the `CError` reference)

```
if(!passwd)
    callback(new EmptyParamError(passwd, ...);
```

**Is there a way to `export` the module or to `require` it that allows me to do this?**

I googled without finding any answer, I also checked all this [interface design patterns for Node.js modules](http://bites.goodeggs.com/posts/export-this/) but no one applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it as a global, though as always when using globals, beware of the side-effects.

```
EmptyParamError = createErrorType(...);
```

That's it. Just leave off the var keyword, and don't set it as a property.

Comment: Thanks! this worked fine.... how did you know about this? can you point me to the documentation that explains this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's only one or two types, you can skip the `CError` variable like this:

```
var EmptyParamError = require('cerror').EmptyParamError;

if(!passwd)
    callback(new EmptyParamError(passwd, ...));
```

If you have multiple types in a single file, there will be multiple `require('cerror')` statements, but I believe there's no significant performance hit there because (if I understand correctly) Node will cache it the first time.